# Retrieve rating from YouTube videos

Tags: php, api, youtube

I've been searching a lot for how to retrieve the Youtube video info and I have some good results, but still have one problem: for some videos my code doesn't retrieve the rating.

My code:

```
$feedURL = 'http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/' . $link;
$entry = simplexml_load_file($feedURL);
$video = parseVideoEntry($entry);

$rating = $video->rating;
$ratingf = (float)$rating*20;

function parseVideoEntry($entry) {      
$obj= new stdClass;

 $gd = $entry->children('http://schemas.google.com/g/2005'); 
 if ($gd->rating) { 
   $attrs = $gd->rating->attributes();
   $obj->rating = $attrs['average']; 
 } else {
   $obj->rating = 0;         
 }
 return $obj;
}
```

So, I'm getting this 0 for some videos and I can't find the reason for it. Do one videos differ from another?

Comment: Add more tags, like PHP, YouTube and API. Regarding the rating: maybe the video isn't rated by anyone yet?

Comment: well... im starting to understand the reason. It is because author of the video closed the rating from view, like for this video
http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=aGqedbRTz3U

Comment: OK.Problem solved? Make your own answer and accept that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will love this tool: [google developers youtube api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#try-it)

It provides the JSON you would get querying the API yourself, an example:

```
{
 "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
 "etag": "\"g-RLCMLrfPIk8n3AxYYPPliWWoo/lmFpi-LTJ4YMpq66PF5yr558nV8\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {

   "id": "9bZkp7q19f0",
   "kind": "youtube#video",
   "etag": "\"g-RLCMLrfPIk8n3AxYYPPliWWoo/g7hwtchXAeaF-Q1DpUEFJXvRfbY\"",
   "statistics": {
    "viewCount": "1621240530",
    "likeCount": "7577258",
    "dislikeCount": "787002",
    "favoriteCount": "0",
    "commentCount": "5969060"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

You can see `like` and `dislike` count inside `statistics`. So whenever you're not sure about the response, check the the tool and see if it has everything you need.